# Debug and Fixing ObjectDisposedException in Visual Studio 2010

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, debugging, xaml, exception

When editing a XAML file I noticed the following error:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException occurred
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'FileCodeModel'.
```

To debug this I ran another instance of Visual Studios and "Debug-> Attach to Process" to the instance of visual studio where the exception was shown.

I was able to catch the exception in the new Instances that started that is attached to the process. I catch the following exception:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException occurred
  Message=Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'FileCodeModel'.
  Source=Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language
  ObjectName=FileCodeModel
  StackTrace:
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.CodeModel.CFileCodeModel.GetCompilation(Boolean fBlockForParses)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.CodeModel.CPartialTypeCollection.EnumerateParts()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.CodeModel.CPartialTypeCollection.get_Count()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.CodeModel.CSlowSnapshot..ctor(CodeElements collection)
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.CodeModel.CPartialTypeCollection.CreateSnapshot()
       at Microsoft.VisualStudio.CSharp.Services.Language.CodeModel.CCollectionBase.GetEnumerator()
       at EnvDTE.CodeElements.GetEnumerator()
       at MS.Internal.VSSymbols.SymbolProvider.GetProperties(String fullName, Boolean isTypeDefinition, Boolean useCodeModel)
       at Microsoft.Xaml.Symbols.IXamlSymbols.GetProperties(String typeName, Boolean isTypeDefinition, Boolean useCodeModel)
       at MS.Internal.Design.Markup.HostedType.BuildProperties(Boolean useCodeModel)
  InnerException:
```

Anybody ever run into this exception in your XAML, and what do you do to fix it.

Comment: To clarify, this is an error in visual studio not an error in your code?

Comment: Are you able to supply the XAML where this happens?

Comment: Right.. it happen in VS2010. This causes the XAML file editing to slow down and VS becomes unresponsive at times. Double clicking on the Exception only leads to TOP of the file, and nothing else.

Comment: Post this to connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Happened to me now. It's looking like "FileCodeModel" is used in XAML Syntax Highlighting / File Structure info used in the IDE.

Comment: I get this too occasionally and it goes away when I build.

Comment: This happened to me when I manually grouped a .xaml.cs and .xaml file by editing the .csproj file.

Comment: please also share the xaml file/code sample that causes it.. might be important evidence..

Comment: Yup, I've currently got this problem in one of my projects too. I (and I imagine all with this problem) don't have anything called `FileCodeModel` in my project. As @David Minor said, it goes away after a build and returns when I edit the .xaml page. It doesn't affect the running of the program, it's just a bit annoying.

Answer (score 2):

Are you running a XAML beautifier? - I've had something similar with an extension that cleans XAML up.

Answer (score 1):

This happened to me when I manually grouped a .xaml.cs and .xaml file by editing the .csproj file. To fix this I:

1. Moved .xaml file to different folder.
2. Opened up solution.
3. Removed .xaml from project.
4. Re-created .xaml file in Visual Studio.
5. Copied the contents of my original .xaml into the newly created .xaml.

After following these steps I no longer got that error message.